# Range Rover Overheating

Tags: coolant

I bought a 2006 LR Range Rover HSE 4.4 liter with 75K (no turbo). At the time of purchase, I had no overheating issues and just nominal tire fixes and some garnish enhancements that I decided to do.

Then I noticed a small leak when I was having the car aligned. I did a pressure test and it yielded that the Thermostat housing was leaking - I didn't decide to fix the issue, so I sent it into a shop, where the work was done. The car started to overheat 3 days later. I purchased a clutch fan & the water pump and replaced them both myself to no avail; the issue still persists.

I just noticed that the reservoir tank is bloated and the lower hose is not warm ... a deeper research shows that the radiator has had some kind of patch work done to it. At this point, I'm thinking of getting the radiator and a new reservoir tank and tackling it myself over the holiday weekend.

My question is ... if I go through with it and replace this radiator and the reservoir tank and it still overheats, is it almost positive that the cars has a blown head gasket or can it be even worst case scenario a blown block engine?

Anyone with any insight - I would greatly appreciate it ...

Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience ...

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that your issue is an obstructed radiator. With a blown engine, you would notice the lack of power. As for a blown head gasket, look at your exhaust colour.

Comment: Wow - that bad? The color coming from the pipes isn't a thick white smoke and the car performed exceptional, no power lacking at all. I purchased a testing kit and it' arriving tomorrow. I'll circle back with results. Thanks for the insight - it's greatly appreceated.

Comment: @Eddie No white smoke means your head gasket is probably ok. Check the thermostat as well, if it doesn't open, the coolant will never hit the radiator to cool off. I'd replace the radiator because of the patch work.